# How to get the Specific Form Field value using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form

```
<form id="post_comment" action="cmt.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="type" value="sub" />
   <textarea id="body"></textarea>
</form>
```

I am accessing the form using this code

```
$("#post_comment").submit(function(event){

    var form = $(this);

});
```

How can I get the value of `<input type="hidden" name="type" value="sub" />` from this form. 
I tried to get using `form.input("type")` but it is not working.

Comment: try var a=$("input:hidden").val();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#post_comment").submit(function(event){
    var inputValue = $("input[name='type']",this).val(); 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using an id like this:

```
<form id="post_comment" action="cmt.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" id='hidden' name="type" value="sub" />
 <textarea id="body"></textarea>
</form>
```

and later:

```
$("#post_comment").submit(function(event){
 var hiddenValue = $("#hidden").val(); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<form id="post_comment" action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="type" value="sub" />
 <textarea id="body"></textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit"/>
</form>



 $(".submit").click(function(){
   var hiddenVal=jQuery("#post_comment .hidden").val();
   //alert(hiddenVal);
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var form = $(this);
var inputValue =  form.find('input[name="type"]').val();

or 

var form = $(this);
var inputValue =  form.find('input:hidden').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach for this 
Consider if you have **multiple forms** with **multiple input fields** having name attribute than this code will be helpful for you :

```
$("#formId input[name='valueOfNameAttribute']").val()
$("#formId textarea[name='message']").val()
```

Hope it'll help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#post_comment").submit(function(event){

        var form = $("input[name='type']").val();

    })
```